# Control buttons using currentScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for currentScript examples and documentation but I didn't see what I want. 
SO now I am not sure did I understand usage of it.
So for example if I have this :

```
var btn = document.createElement("button") ;        // Create a <button> element
    var surv = document.createTextNode("Get Started");
    btn.appendChild(surv);
    btn.setAttribute("id", "btn1");
    btn.className = "button2";
```

What is the best way to control it? 
What I want is this:

```
<script 
  src="http://xxx/buttons.js"

  button-variant="button-1"
  button-color="2000"
  button-width="200px"
  button-height="150px">
</script>
```

I want control of this button, so I want to can change all this properties from my script. Variant of button, them height, width and color. 
So should I use currentScript or some other function, and what is the best way to do it?
So if i type variant 2 to autmaticaly change the button, or if I type other color. 
 
I hope that I ask understandable question. 
All advice and help is welcome

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Supersharp OK. What I am looking for is the way that I can control the background of the button which is not on my website. I am making embeded code. So when someone pick background-color, I want to have control on it, and if I don't like it to change it.